# Vue md-input with Vuex updating only in one direction

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue app with an input element bound to a  like this:

```html
<template>
   <input v-model="this.$store.state.myvalue"/>
</template>
```

and VueX `store/index.js`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    myvalue: null
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

When I modify `myvalue` with Vue devtools, the input's value changes too, but when I change the value in the input field, the state variable does not change. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to VueX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I change the value in the input field, the state variable does not change.

It does change, Dev tools just don't show the change. You can validate by changing the template to this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="$store.state.myvalue">
    <div>{{ $store.state.myvalue }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

But you should not mutate Vuex state like this! Vuex allows it but it's not recommended. Reason is your state changes should be traceable (easier to find which component changed the state and when). That's why Vuex recommends changing the state only by using mutations. Mutation is basically a function which is called when state change is needed.

Best way to do 2-way data binding against Vuex state is using computed properties with getter/seter like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="myvalue">
    <div>{{ myvalue }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  computed: {
    myvalue: {
      get: function() {
        return this.$store.state.myvalue;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.$store.commit("change_myvalue", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You need to define a mutation in your store to make it work like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    myvalue: ""
  },
  mutations: {
      change_myvalue(state, value) {
          state.myvalue = value
      }
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

You can read more about mutations [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Comment: Thanks. Is the reason devtools doesn't show the change because it's not traceable through a mutation?

Comment: No, Dev Tools should be able to detect direct changes like this. Maybe [its just a bug in Dev Tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1080)

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not suggested to use vuex state directly bound with view layer, instead vuex is better to use for business logic, you can achieve changing the state on user input by below mentioned ways:

> [1] two-way data binding: use v-model directive & bind the state in
>   it. On user input, the state will be updated. On changing state
>   programmatically, the element's value will be updated & reflect on
>   dom.

.vue file

```
<template>
   <input v-model="$store.state.myvalue"/>
</template>
```

> [2] manually create two-way data-binding.

.vue file

```
<template>
   <input :value="getMyValue" @input="handleInput"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 methods: {
  handleInput (value) {
   this.$store.commit('UPDATE_MY_VALUE', { value })
  }
 },
 computed: {
  getMyValue () {
   return this.$store.state.myvalue
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

store file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    myvalue: null
  },
  mutations: {
   UPDATE_MY_VALUE (state, { value }) {
    state.myvalue = value
   }
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

Comment: Oops I wrote v-bind not v-model in my original question, so what I'm doing is just the first of those. But why isn't it working for me?